# How can I have a conditional statement remain true for an x amount of candles?

Tags: if-statement, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am attempting to write a script with two indicators. The problem is, they never both ping true on the same candle (Usually one or two candles apart). So my goal is to have both parts of the conditional statement still be true, even if respectively it was true x candles before.

I've tried messing with ta.highest, and [x] notation. However, with the [x] notation, it is only referencing one candle instead of all five at the same time. In the end, I am hoping to have a conditional statement with two parts. With the whole statement being true if both conditions have been met in the past x candles.

I am attempting to create a strategy that incorporates a simple RSI indicator:

```
//@version=5
indicator("RSI Indicator", overlay=true)

// Input parameters
rsiLength = input(14, "RSI Length")
overboughtLevel = input(70, "Overbought Level")
oversoldLevel = input(30, "Oversold Level")

// Calculate RSI
rsiValue = ta.rsi(close, rsiLength)

// Condition variables
longCondition = crossover(rsiValue, oversoldLevel)
shortCondition = crossunder(rsiValue, overboughtLevel)
```

Aswell as a simple ATR indicator:

```
atrPeriod = input(10, "ATR Length")
factor = input.float(3.0, "Factor", step = 0.01)

[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(factor, atrPeriod)
```

I'd then like to call a strategy to enter, if both conditions above are met:

```
if ta.change(direction) < 0 and longCondition
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if ta.change(direction) > 0 and shortCondition
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

I ended up just using

```
ta.barssince(longCondition) = xBarsBack
```

and then was able to use a conditional statement

```
if xBarsBack < x 
   strategy.entry('long')
```

It checks back until the condition is true and returns that as an int. if < x then the condition passes.

Comment: You'll need to share your code if you want some help. What your describing sounds like you'll need to use booleans and a counter

Comment: Added code in, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do what it sounds like your describing. You'll need to add in exit criteria and you can adjust the code as needed, but should give you an idea of the boolean and counter idea

```
//@version=5
strategy("RSI Indicator", overlay=true)

// Inputs
rsiLength = input.int(14, "RSI Length")
overboughtLevel = input.float(70, "Overbought Level")
oversoldLevel = input.float(30, "Oversold Level")
atrPeriod = input.int(10, "ATR Length")
factor = input.float(3.0, "Factor", step = 0.01)
barLimit = input.int(5, 'Bar Limit')

//variables
var directionChange = false
var startCounter = false
var counter = 0

// Calculate RSI / Supertrend
rsiValue = ta.rsi(close, rsiLength)
[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(factor, atrPeriod)

// Condition variables
longCondition = ta.crossover(rsiValue, oversoldLevel)
shortCondition = ta.crossunder(rsiValue, overboughtLevel)

if ta.change(direction) < 0 or ta.change(direction) > 0
    directionChange := true
    startCounter := true

counter := startCounter ? counter + 1 : counter

if directionChange and counter <= barLimit and longCondition
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if directionChange and counter <= barLimit and shortCondition
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

if counter > barLimit
    startCounter := false
    counter := 0
    directionChange := false
```

Comment: Giving it a glance and it looks great! Will test this out soon.